# C# New method breaks existing one

Tags: c#, insert, load, crud

I'm writing a class for saving and retrieving an object into a database. I'm having issues with my class because I added a method to load values from the database which suddenly broke my save method.

My save method, which worked fine before I added the load method, ceased to update existing entries after the load method was added. It still does a fine job of inserting new entries into the DB, but it no longer updates.  If I remove the load method, it continues to update and insert fine, but as soon as I add back the load method, I start having issues.

Code examples at: http://forums.asp.net/p/1825368/5072214.aspx/1?New+method+breaks+existing+one

Comment: How are you accessing the DB, with ADO or a high level framework?

Comment: Also, aren't you messing up with `UserID` at your codebehind?

Comment: Why did you create a method to load data? Its not good style to open a connection in one location locally, then close it somewhere else outside of that method. I think that's what's causing it.

Comment: @Andre Calil I'm using ADO. What problem do you see with UserID?

Comment: @Bob I'm still somewhat new to this. Can you explain why creating a method to load data is a bad practice? Also, do you have any suggestions for fixing the issue? Would it be better to assign the datareader to a list or an array and then manipulate that, or should I do it all from the codebehind?

Comment: @KinsDotNet I didn't see any problem, actually, I was just wondering. You should close the connection at the end of the `Load` method, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: @KinsDotNet Its not that creating a load data method is bad practice, its that you open a connection in the method without closing it in the same location. From your code, the only way it gets closed is if you remember to call the Close() method for the DataReader. Its like leaving your house, and hoping someone else remembers to close the door for you. (A bit exaggerated, heh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close the connection in the Load() method.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to handle it right, but what I attempted to do was to close the connection from the codebehind after I'm done reading. I guess that's probably either a bad practice or altogether incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Usually what I do is execute the reader, grab the data from it in a data structure that suits my needs and then close the connection. This practice assures that when you open it, you close it and makes it slightly more readable. The Load() method should "load" the data for reading instead of returning an SqlDataReader. Depending on what you have to do with the data, you might want to even define a custom obj to store it all. This way you can use the generic List<T> to store everything and access it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never closing the initial connection used in the load method and are creating a new one in the other method. Maybe this is the reason? It is hard to tell without Exception text. Can you post the exception?

It looks like you aren't calling `CitizenSave` anywhere in your code.

Comment: There is no exception at all. When I attempt to update an entry, the page does a postback with no changes being registered.

Comment: @KinsDotNet It looks like you aren't calling `CitizenSave` anywhere in your code.

Comment: It's called from the .aspx file (which I haven't posted) as a button click event.

Comment: @KinD Set a breakpoint in there and see if it is getting hit correctly.